# does it make sense that my BST performs better than my heap for deleteMin?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, priority-queue

i have a basic implementation (from the Weiss Data structures and algorithms in C++ textbook) for the heap and the BST. i timed their execution for deleteMin, using heap.deleteMin and bst.remove(bst.findMin()). to my surprise, the BST actually outperforms the heap by a small margin (roughly 1.5x faster). i'm in release mode on visual studio 2022.

is this to be expected, or am i doing something wrong? i was under the impression that the heap was much faster than a BST for implementing priority queues. thanks!

main:

```
int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree<int> bst;
    BinaryHeap<int> heap;
    
    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;
    int n = 1000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        heap.insert(rand() % 10000000);
        bst.insert(rand() % 10000000);
    }

    start = std::clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        //heap.deleteMin(); // 0.099s
        bst.remove(bst.findMin()); // 0.06s
    duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "time: " << duration << '\n';    
}
```

BST:

```
template<typename Comparable>
class BinarySearchTree
{

public:
    BinarySearchTree() 
        : root{nullptr}
    {
       
    }
    
    BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree& rhs)
    {
        root = clone(rhs.root); 
    }

    ~BinarySearchTree()
    {
        makeEmpty(root); 
    }

    const Comparable& findMin()const
    {
        return findMin(root)->element;
    }

    const Comparable& findMax()const
    {
        return findMax(root)->element;
    }

    bool contains(const Comparable& x)const
    {
        return contains(x, root);
    }

    void insert(const Comparable& x)
    {
        insert(x, root);
    }

    void remove(const Comparable& x)
    {
        remove(x, root); 
    }

private:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
        Comparable element;
        BinaryNode* left;
        BinaryNode* right;
        BinaryNode(const Comparable& theElement, BinaryNode* lt, BinaryNode* rt)
            : element{theElement}, left{lt}, right{rt}{}
        BinaryNode(const Comparable&& theElement, BinaryNode* lt, BinaryNode* rt)
            : element{ std::move(theElement) }, left{ lt }, right{ rt } {}
    };

    BinaryNode* root; 

    BinaryNode* clone(BinaryNode* t)const
    {
        if (t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else
            return new BinaryNode{ t->element, clone(t->left), clone(t->right) }; 
    }

    bool contains(const Comparable& x, BinaryNode* t)const
    {
        if (t == nullptr)
            return false;
        else if (x < t->element)
            return contains(x, t->left);
        else if (t->element < x)
            return contains(x, t->right);
        else return true; //found
    }

    BinaryNode* findMin(BinaryNode* t) const
    {
        if (t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        if (t->left == nullptr)
            return t;
        return findMin(t->left);
    }

    BinaryNode* findMax(BinaryNode* t)const
    {
        if (t == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        if (t->right == nullptr)
            return t;
        return findMin(t->right);
    }

    void insert(const Comparable& x, BinaryNode*& t)
    {
        if (t == nullptr)
            t = new BinaryNode(x, nullptr, nullptr);
        else if (x < t->element)
            insert(x, t->left);
        else if (t->element <= x)
            insert(x, t->right);
        else; // duplicate, do nothing
    }

    void insert(Comparable&& x, BinaryNode*& t)
    {
        if (t == nullptr)
            t = new BinaryNode{ std::move(x),nullptr, nullptr };
        else if (x < t->element)
            insert(std::move(x), t->left);
        else if (t->element <= x)
            insert(std::move(x), t->right);
        else //duplicate, do nothing
            ;
    }

    void remove(const Comparable& x, BinaryNode*& t)
    {
        if (t == nullptr)
            return;
        if (x < t->element)
            remove(x, t->left);
        else if (t->element <= x)
            remove(x, t->right);
        else if (t->left != nullptr && t->right != nullptr) // two children
        {
            t->element = findMin(t->right)->element;
            remove(t->element, t->right);
        }
        else
        {
            BinaryNode* oldNode = t;
            t = (t->left != nullptr) ? t->left : t->right; 
            delete oldNode; 
        }
    }

    void makeEmpty(BinaryNode*& t)
    {
        if (t != nullptr)
        {
            makeEmpty(t->left);
            makeEmpty(t->right);
            delete t;
        }
        t = nullptr;
    }

};
```

binary heap:

```
template < typename Comparable>
class BinaryHeap
{
public:
    explicit BinaryHeap(int capacity = 100)
        :arr(capacity), currentSize{0}
    {}

    explicit BinaryHeap(const std::vector<Comparable>& items)
        : arr(items.size() + 10), currentSize{ items.size() }
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i)
            arr[i + 1] = items[i];
        buildHeap();
    }
    
    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return currentSize == 0;
    }
    const Comparable& findMin() const
    {
        return arr[1];
    }
    
    void insert(const Comparable& x)
    {
        if (currentSize == arr.size() - 1)
            arr.resize(arr.size() * 2);
        
        // Percolate up
        int hole = ++currentSize;
        Comparable copy = x;
        
        arr[0] = std::move(copy);
        for (; x < arr[hole / 2]; hole /= 2)
            arr[hole] = std::move(arr[hole / 2]);
        arr[hole] = std::move(arr[0]);
    }

    void insert(Comparable&& x)
    {
        if (currentSize == arr.size() - 1)
            arr.resize(arr.size() * 2);

        // Percolate up
        int hole = ++currentSize;

        arr[0] = std::move(x);
        for (; x < arr[hole / 2]; hole /= 2)
            arr[hole] = std::move(arr[hole / 2]);
        arr[hole] = std::move(arr[0]);
    }
 
     /**
* Remove the minimum item.
* Throws UnderflowException if empty.
*/
    void deleteMin()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw UnderflowException{ };
        
        arr[1] = std::move(arr[currentSize--]);
        percolateDown(1);
    }
    
    /**
    * Remove the minimum item and place it in minItem.
    * Throws UnderflowException if empty.
    */
    void deleteMin(Comparable & minItem)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw UnderflowException{ };
        
        minItem = std::move(arr[1]);
        arr[1] = std::move(arr[currentSize--]);
        percolateDown(1);
    }
    
    void makeEmpty();
    
 private:
    int currentSize; // Number of elements in heap
    std::vector<Comparable> arr; // The heap array
    
    /**
    * Establish heap order property from an arbitrary
    * arrangement of items. Runs in linear time.
    */
    void buildHeap()
    {
        for (int i = currentSize / 2; i > 0; --i)
            percolateDown(i);
    }

    /**
    * Internal method to percolate down in the heap.
    * hole is the index at which the percolate begins.
    */
    void percolateDown(int hole)
    {
        int child;
        Comparable tmp = std::move(arr[hole]);

        for (; hole * 2 <= currentSize; hole = child)
        {
            child = hole * 2;
            if (child != currentSize && arr[child + 1] < arr[child])
                ++child;
            if (arr[child] < tmp)
                arr[hole] = std::move(arr[child]);
            else
                break;
        }
        arr[hole] = std::move(tmp);
    }
};
```

Comment: I think it's because the BST is not balanced, so it doesn't rebalance after every removal. Maybe this also leads to more cache friendly access patterns in your benchmark. But it also means that the BST effectively becomes a linked list in the worst case.

Comment: I would suggest creating a single list of numbers and adding the same list to each data structure to make sure the data is distributed in the same way for a better comparison.

Comment: Another point is that you aren't including heap build time, the biggest advantage of a heap is your ability to build it in O(n) time. But you're adding items one by one. (But that's not your question)

Comment: To answer your question could it be that percolateDown() isn't very efficient? Try defining a variable called hole2 = hole*2 and reuse that inside the loop. Does that make a difference performance wise?

Or maybe try hole+hole instead of hole*2.

The only other thing I see is that you call std::move() a lot of times in the heap whereas in the BST you perform just one deletion and a couple of assignments at worse.

Comment: @krisz another factor is since he's using random data the BST probably going to be relatively well balanced. Try it with some purposely bad data like n,n-1,n-2,n-3,...,2,1,0 and maybe the results will become terrible for the BST since you'll have a linked list situation.